# Too large bottom margin with xtab (or supertabular)

Tags: page-breaking, supertabular, xtab

I am using the xtab package to add a long table in a business report.
A premature page break is added at each page, leaving a large bottom margin.
Same problem occurs with package supertabular (on which xtab is based).
Any ideas?

Related: [Long tables (spanning multiple pages), put side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269018/long-tables-spanning-multiple-pages-put-side-by-side)

I put a sample below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|l|}
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Just for reference:

The best result that I could get, is by using the following:

- The "nofoot" option of the geometry package.
- The xtab package for the table
- The xentrystretch{0} command of the xtab package.

Comment: The `supertabular` package makes some (bad) assumptions about the space to reserve for rows and it adds a rather large overshoot. This doesn't happen with `longtable`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267109/longtable-appears-to-prevent-enlargethispage-from-working/

Comment: @egreg I cannot use longtable, because I need to put two long tables in two parallely constructed columns, using the paracol package.

Answer (score 2):

I added **\shrinkheight{-2in}** in two different places and the 3-page sample was reduced to two pages. Check this out:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|l|}
\shrinkheight{-2in}
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
\shrinkheight{-2in}
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
a & 4 \\
a & 5 \\
a & 6 \\
a & 7 \\
a & 8 \\
a & 9 \\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The report will created programmatically without the possibility of making manual adjustments.

Comment: Just for reference:
The best result that I could get, is by using the following:

- The "nofoot" option of the geometry package.
- The xtab package for the table
- The xentrystretch{0} command of the xtab package.

Answer (score 1):

The package `supertabular` overestimates row heights in order to be sure to split the table before the page break.

Here's a proof:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\estimate@lineht}{1\p@}{-1.5\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{|l|l|}
a & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
a & 2 \\
a & 3 \\
[...]
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

(fill in the data). You'll see that the chunks end almost at the page break.

[image]